# docker-compose with nginx and php:8-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I try to add php support to my nginx running inside docker. But starting of the service fails.

That is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  nginxproxy:
      image: nginx:mainline-alpine
      command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 48h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
      environment:
        - TZ=${TZ}
      volumes:
        - ./data/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
        - ./data/nginx/websites:/var/www/
      depends_on:
         - php-fpm
      links:
         - php-fpm
      restart: always
      network_mode: "host"

  php-fpm:
      image: php:8-fpm
      ports:
        - 9001:9000
      volumes:
        - ./data/nginx/websites:/var/www/
```

./data/nginx/websites containes severall webroots of different vhosts.

When I try to bring everything up, nginx is able to start, but php:8-fpm fails to start.
docker-compose logs does only show "Attaching to"

I am not able to find out more error messages oder whats wrong here.

Comment: Based on your example above, I receive `ERROR: for docker_stuff_nginxproxy_1  Cannot create container for service nginxproxy: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior
`
You might want to change (or remove) the `network_mode`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue before. It found out my php-fpm was a problem. in my default.conf. I change the default fastcgi_pass to **fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;**

Here is my config

server {

```
listen *:80;
index index.php index.html;
server_name localhost;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/project;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

}

Article Reference: [How to setup PHP 8, NGINX, PHP-FPM and Alpine with Docker](https://www.reviewcurious.com/how-to-setup-php-8-nginx-php-fpm-and-alpine-with-docker/)